# Login to website with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

how can I login to http://minecraft-server-list.com/login/login.php using HtmlUnit? The login form doesn't seem to have an ID so I can't get it by using getFormByName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the form by using xpath 
 `HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='login.php']");`

And then get username and password fields E.g.

```
final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName("Username");
final HtmlPasswordInput pwd =  form.getInputByName("password");
```

After then set the credentials

```
textField.setValueAttribute("foo");
pwd.setValueAttribute("bar");
```

Get the login button and perform click

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login").click();
```

Comment: @sol4me: xpath of which element?

Comment: @Guru xpath for a particular html element in our case its ```form``` element